# linux gpg how to specify crypto strength

Tags: linux, gpg

When using `gpg` to encrypt a file, I use

```
gpg -c important.docx
```

but it always uses 2048 how do you specify 4096?

I am looking RSA 4096 + RSA 4096

Thank you.

Any help appreciated.

doop

Answer (score 5):

You can't get RSA-4096 encryption from the `-c` switch.  Note:

```
$ echo test | gpg -acv
…
gpg: using cipher AES
…
```

Using the `--version` switch:

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.2.24
libgcrypt 1.8.7
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /Users/fox/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

For symmetric ciphers (the `-c` switch) the algorithms are any of IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH, CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, or CAMELLIA256, which you can select between with `--cipher-algo [algorithm]`. The default, AES, is 128-bit. Any of the 256-bit options would likely be an improvement.

RSA encryption is used for asymmetric encryption where both parties have public and private keys.  In that case, the number of bits is fixed at the time of key-creation.

Comment: hi, thx for the reply. just using the -c option are you able to make the encryption stronger? is aes256 the strongest? thx

Comment: AES256 is going to be stronger than the default (128-bit) AES, but others may be preferred. Which one is a matter of opinion, though generally i see AES and TWOFISH being suggested

Comment: how do you set the strength?gpg -c ? could you give me an example?

Comment: as written; rather than just `gpg -c` it'd be `gpg -c --cipher-algo AES256` for example

Comment: thank you! is there a config file somewhere, that i use nano to set the defalut? last question i think. are you able to enrypt twice or 3 times say gpg -c --cipher-algo AES256 --cipher-algo TWOFISH important.docx?

Comment: with 2 passwords one for aes256 and one for twofish?

Comment: it looks like you can put a line reading `cipher-algo AES256` in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` to make that the default. as for double-encryption, you can of course just run `gpg -c` on the output of the first pass if you want to do that